# Create RelNode for SELECT 1

Tags: apache-calcite

Which API should I use in `org.apache.calcite.tools.RelBuilder` to produce `RelNode` representing query `SELECT 1` in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RelNode r = builder.values(new String[] {"c"}, 1).build();
```